# Best way to add features after last convolutional layer, before fully-connected layers?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working on a regression problem related to chess. The output will depend on about 68 values that are given by Stockfish's static evaluation function ([example output shown here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/30110/how-to-get-static-evaluation-from-stockfish-in-case-that-a-king-is-in-check)), as well as the state of the board. However, the static eval features should not be passed through the CNN, only through the final fully-connected layers. Therefore I want to have some convolutional layers take the (one-hot encoded) board state down to a flat vector, then extend it with the other features before passing the full vector to a fully-connected layer.

How can I use Tensorflow to combine these two feature vectors (the result from the CNN and the other game-related features) within a single `Layer` type that can be added to a `Sequential`? I couldn't find anything that would handle this in the docs. Would subclassing `Layer` be the only way to go?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Noted, but this question is indeed about programming, see second paragraph. I am not questioning on the theory.

Comment: Fair point, retracting the vote.